# How to setup PWA in magento 2.3.1?

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa, pwa-studio

I've installed Magento 2.3.1 and trying to use PWA but it's not working, I have followed the below link 
https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-magento-pwa-studio-with-poc-c54c33f8d038

but when i was trying to create symlink by using the following commands

```
ln -s /var/www/html/magento/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-module app/code/Magento/

ln -s /var/www/html/magento/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept app/design/frontend/Magento/venia
```

Does anybody know how to create a PWA project? I'm Working in Windows Machine

Comment: Refer the link you can help for same.
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/

Comment: Thanks Kirti, I went throw this also but its not working.

Comment: what trouble are you facing ?

Comment: When I'm running the above commands its throws error and while running "yarn run build"  also throws error.

Comment: Use cmd: sudo yarn run build
and check.

Comment: I tried both ways i got the below error   $ yarn run build
$ BABEL_ENV=development babel src --out-dir esm --root-mode 'upward' --source-maps
$ BABEL_ENV=production babel src --out-dir dist --root-mode 'upward' --source-maps
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
Directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\poc\pwa-studio\packages\peregrine

Answer (score 3):

**Setup PWA (Linux os)**

Step 1 :  Install magento 2.3.1

Step 2 : Install/upgrade node

Use n module from npm in order to upgrade node

```
sudo npm install n -g
```

For the latest stable version:

```
sudo n stable
```

For the latest version:

```
sudo n latest
```

Step 3: Install/update yarn :

```
sudo npm install --global yarn

sudo npm upgrade --global yarn
```

Step 4 : Install node-gyp - Node.js native addon build tool

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```

Step 5 : Clone the PWA Studio repository

Go to html root and run :

```
git clone https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio.git
```

After running this you will get pwa-studio folder

Step 6: Install PWA Studio dependencies

```
sudo yarn install
```

Step 7: Specify the Magento backend server

```
Under the packages/venia-concept directory, copy .env.dist into a new .env file:
```

Example command:

```
sudo cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env
```

change in .env file (this will be your magento URL, not admin url):

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://release-dev-231-npzdaky-zddsyhrdimyra.us-4.magentosite.cloud/"
```

Step 8: Now create a build

```
sudo yarn run build
```

Step 9: Run the server

```
sudo yarn run watch:venia
```

Starts the Venia storefront development environment only.

```
sudo yarn run watch:all
```

Runs the full PWA Studio developer experience, which include Venia hot-reloading and concurrent Buildpack/Peregrine rebuilds.

```
sudo yarn run build && yarn run stage:venia
```

Generates build artifacts and runs the staging environment, which uses more compressed assets and more closely reflects production.

Once you run one of the above command you will get the virtul url created by PWA.

NOTE: if you are rood user then use sudo.

Follow Magento 2 officical dev docs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/pwa/

Comment: I already tried from the official website but noting is clear.

Comment: Actully you need to install the third party setups like yarn, node as recommended for PWA

Comment: You are right, i installed pwa-studio, node module and yarn also, actually I'm working in windows machine.

Comment: ohk, I'll update command for window as well, you just need to install all the required softwares then those commands will work perfectly.

Comment: I'll be thankful to you :)  if is it possible please guide me step by step like the above answer.

Comment: sure, I'll do it

Comment: Have you install babel?

Comment: npm install babel-cli babel-core --save-dev
 , refer:https://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/setup-babel/

Comment: I've done but still is not working @SaphalJha can you please send steps for windows? as you sent for Linux.

Comment: What is your nodejs and yarn versions?

Comment: yarn run v1.15.2
node v11.11.0

Comment: @VinodKumar did you get the solution for windows,if please tell steps

Comment: Not yet, Still waiting for reply

Comment: @SaphalJha  point number 7 Specify the Magento backend server  -> I am unable to view .env.dist file is there any solution?

Comment: npx @magento/pwa-buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept